# orientation change working strangely from landscape to portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

after creating the app in landscape mode . I am adding the menu view for my application in portrait view
but when I tried to change the view from both in xib and programatically
  the view changed but the mobile simulator is still shown as landscape view along with showing the previous view background
I have gone through many of the question regarding the orientation but nothing seems to work for me

here is the pic reference of app
[image]

and the code for creating the button is
easy button code is

```
easee = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[easee addTarget:self 
            action:@selector(easy:)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[easee setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radioButtonDisabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
easee.frame = CGRectMake(85.0, 86.0, 22.0, 22.0);
[self.view addSubview:easee];
```

Comment: Please show us some code that pertains to the position of some of the buttons.

Comment: Can you post your autorotation method. If you are using the latest iOS you may need to declare the masks for autorotation.

Comment: @Spectravideo328 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { 
 // Return YES for supported orientations 
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); 
} the code for orientation

Comment: Are the buttons locations set using code or just IB?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 :: the label are created in .xib using interface builder and the button are created dynamically in code by giving the the coordinates info :

Comment: @Spectravideo328 button location are set in the code:

Comment: Tahir, please post the code of how you are setting one of the buttons!

Comment: @Spectravideo328 i have edited the question :: please check the code for the button

Answer (score 0):

The view frame does not rotate when the device rotates. Only the view bounds within the frame rotates.
If the placement of your UIView objects are different in portrait and landscape and you have already tried struts and springs and that is not enough, then you have to programmatically code their position. In that case, use bounds.

```
easee.bounds = CGRectMake(85.0, 86.0, 22.0, 22.0);
```

Keep in mind, that you will need to have different code (coordinates) for portrait and Landscape depending on the object positions in the view, in the orientation.

Please read the view PG: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html

it will give you a good understanding of view, bounds, frames, etc...

Hope this helps.

Comment: i only want this view to have a potrait view and the frame is set for that case :: any help regarding the

Comment: why did you say in your question :"after creating the app in landscape mode"

Comment: i got your point >> but the question first part is to show the menu screen to portait view only>>> no need to write the seperate code for orientation because i only want to show it to a portait view::

Comment: because all other view are in landscape view::